# How to get Transparent or white background color in Home Tab circle when its selected or unselected

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
 PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset(
          "assets/homeScreenImages/home_active.png",
        ),
        inactiveIcon: Image.asset(
          "assets/homeScreenImages/home_unactive.png",
        ),
        title: ("Home"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.orange[700],
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
```

Comment: what about others tab, do you get the color?

Comment: Yes , I get the color.....

Comment: can you add `home_active` and `home_unactive` images.

Comment: No......I have specific image for this purpose

Comment: If image have no color issue, change `activeColorPrimary: Colors.white` and also try `Image.asset(
          "assets/homeScreenImages/home_active.png", color:Colors.white
        ),`
But I think it would be better if you add ` PersistentBottomNavBar` it may have  selected color or something similar

Comment: I already using PersistentBottomNavBar`

Comment: can you add full `navBar` widget. People may can find it out for you.